# ImportError: No module named sip

Tags: ros, nxt, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was working a few months ago and I have not touched ROS since. I am using ROS electric and Ubuntu 10.04, and I am following the tutorials on how to make ROS work with Legos NXT. When I type `roslaunch robot.launch` I get the error:

```
respawning...
[nxt_ros-2] restarting process
process[nxt_ros-2]: started with pid [6573]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/nxt/nxt_ros/scripts/nxt_ros.py", line 49, in <module>
    from PyKDL import Rotation
ImportError: No module named sip
[nxt_ros-2] process has died [pid 6573, exit code 1].
log files: /home/joel/.ros/log/19cd638e-84de-11e5-a689-0026b9c3b537/nxt_ros-2*.log
```

I do not now what is causing this problem and am not too knowledgeable with ROS or Linux. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220572/importerror:-no-module-named-sip/) by [Joelac0193](https://answers.ros.org/users/22079/joelac0193/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install python-sip:
http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html

---

Originally posted by [SReuter](https://answers.ros.org/users/3248/sreuter/) with karma: 16 on 2015-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-11-21**:
Try `sudo apt-get install python-sip` to install Ubuntu's version, before following the source installation instructions.